# Arranging number in ascending order with different methods in Python

Tags: python

It's giving `TypeError` saying `'NoneType' object is not iterable`.
How to solve need help.

My code is listed below:

```py
def ascending(a, b, c):
    l = [a, b, c]
    if a < b and a < c:
        d = a
    elif b < c:
        d = b
    else:
         d = c
    l = l.remove(d)
    e = max(l)
    f = l[0]
    list = []
    list = list.append(d)
    list = list.append(f)
    list = list.append(e)
    return list

s = ascending(5, 7, 3)
print(s)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ascending.py", line 21, in <module>
    s = ascending(5,7,3)
  File "test_ascending.py", line 13, in ascending
    e = max(l)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Post your code and errors as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please try to formulate a specific question that you want answered.

Comment: Work on your question and post ur solution which have not worked

Comment: Variable names are case-sensitive in Python which means that that `Foobar` is not the same as `foobar`. For future reference please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: thank you so much well bro how can solve none type object is not iterable    def ascending(a,b,c):
  l = [a,b,c]
  if a < b and a < c:
      d = a
  elif b < c:
      d = b
  else:
       d = c 
  l = l.remove(d)
  e = max(l)
  f = l[0]
  list = []
  list = list.append(d)
  list = list.append(f)
  list = list.append(e)
  return list


s = ascending(5,7,3)
print(s)

Comment: i cant upload image of a code because i don't have enough point

Comment: Putting a link to an image of the code in your question is equivalent — and has the same problems — as uploading and embedding one into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` is because `l.remove(d)` doesn't remove anything, so the statement:

```
l = l.remove(d)
```

sets the value of `l` to `None`.

Likewise, `list.append()` doesn't have a return value so the line:

```
list = list.append(d)
```

and similar statements have the same problem.

Although it's not currently causing any problems, but you also shouldn't give variables the same name as any Python built-in, such as `list` which is a built-in class. Doing so can cause problems and make your code harder to understand to folks who know the language.

Here's a working version of your code with all the modifications made to it so it now executes without errors:

```
def ascending(a,b,c):
    l = [a,b,c]
    if a < b and a < c:
        d = a
    elif b < c:
        d = b
    else:
         d = c
    l.remove(d)
    e = max(l)
    f = l[0]
    my_list = []
    my_list.append(d)
    my_list.append(f)
    my_list.append(e)
    return my_list

s = ascending(5,7,3)
print(s)  # -> [3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: thank you well can we supply input to the array in python I just tried but got an error something just like this                                                                                                                         ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "a = arr.array('i',[passing])"
I don't understand what it meant base 10

Comment: Darkstar: Sorry, I can't tell from that fragment of code what's wrong. An error message like that usually means that the conversion of string to a `int` was attempted but one or more of the characters the string isn't a decimal digit, i.e. `'0', '1',... '9'` — so you should ask a new question...and be sure to specify the type of `arr.array`.